# Error while creating PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to create an Pivot table. I recorded the macros, and then simplified it to easy understanding.

While executing the code, I get error

> subscript out of range.

I checked with the worksheet name, it is the same name I have defined.

I'm clueless, why it is not working. Below, is the code I tried.

```
 Sub table()
    Dim pvtcache As PivotCache
    Dim pvttbl As pivottable
    Dim pvtsht As Worksheet

    Set pvtcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
      "Preparation Sheet!R1C1:R1048576C9")       
    Set pvtsht = Worksheets("LP")

    On Error Resume Next
      Set pvttbl = pvtsht.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If pvttbl Is Nothing Then
        Set pvttbl = pvtsht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtcache, TableDestination:=pvtsht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable3")

        With pvttbl
            With .PivotFields("DL")
                .Orientation = xlRowField
                .Position = 1
            End With
            With .PivotFields("Colour")
                .Orientation = xlColumnField
                .Position = 1
            End With
        End With   
    Else
        ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
        pvttbl.ChangePivotCache pvtcache
    End If
End Sub
```

below is the code, from macros

```
Sub Macro8() 
    Sheets.Add

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
      "Preparation Sheet!R1C1:R1048576C9", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
      CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2" _
      , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("DL")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
      "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Colour"), "Count of Colour", xlCount

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Colour")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us what line you're getting the error on?

Comment: I get error in Set pvttbl = pvtsht.PivotTables("PivotTable3") @dwirony

Comment: That means there is no pivot table called "PivotTable3".

Comment: This line of code looks fine and should work if there is a pivot table called `PivotTable3` in your worksheet `LP`. And what I ask myself how can you get an error on that line if you used `On Error Resume Next` which mutes errors? That's odd.

Comment: @braX there exist an pivottable3

Comment: @peh, Even I am confused, how it could happen. I am using the same code, to generate a pivottable in another worksheet of same workbook, that works great.

Comment: I tested your procedure `Sub table()` and it works like expected (both generating the PivotTable3 **and** updating it). I cannot reproduce your issue. And I ask again how you can get an error in that line if you used `On Error Resume Next`. Any chance that there are more than one workbook opened?

Comment: I am also wondering on the same Point as mentioned by you. No, only one work book is open.

Comment: Just in case which Office version are you using? I tested it with *Excel 2016 x64 bit Edition* maybe anyone can verify that with exact the same version as you use. I can't reproduce it and so I got no idea of what is going wrong here.

Comment: @peh I am using Excel 2013

Comment: Just in case did you turn on *Break On All Errors* in the option menu (choose Options from the Tools menu, and click the General tab)? If so turn it back to default *Break On Unhandled Errors*. See [Five tips for handling errors in VBA](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/)

Comment: @peh, Its proper.

Comment: @peh, Just in case, is it possible for you to frame a new code from the recorded macros as i did ? May be i will crosscheck with that

Comment: Check my edited answer to see if this alternative way works. But still odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If your worksheet names contain spaces `"Preparation Sheet!R1C1:R1048576C9"` you need to enclose the worksheet name in `''`

```
"'Preparation Sheet'!R1C1:R1048576C9"
```

or avoid spaces in it.

---

**Edit**

Add this function to your module

```
Public Function PivotTableExistsInWorksheet(pvWorksheet As Worksheet, pvTableName As String) As Boolean
    Dim pvTable As PivotTable

    PivotTableExistsInWorksheet = False 'Default

    For Each pvTable In pvWorksheet.PivotTables
        If pvTable.Name = pvTableName Then
            PivotTableExistsInWorksheet = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next pvTable
End Function
```

and use

```
If PivotTableExistsInWorksheet(pvtsht, "PivotTable3") Then
    Set pvttbl = pvtsht.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
End If
```

instead of the `On Error Resume Next … Goto 0` block to see if this works.

Comment: @Mikz Then you got an additional issue too. But you still need to enclose worksheet names containing spaces into `''`

Comment: i would do that now.

Comment: now i am getting an error Application defined or obejct defined error in the line  Set pvttbl = pvtsht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pvtcache, TableDestination:=pvtsht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable3") @Peh

Comment: @Mikz I'm sorry but I have to ask again: Are you 100% sure that there is a worksheet called "LP"? If yes I'm really out of ideas. This is 100% working for me.

Comment: Ok you can test this yourself. Create a new clean workbook, create 2 blank worksheets in it (`LP` and `Preparation Sheet`) copy the data into the `Preparation Sheet` add the procedure `Sub table()` into VBA and run it (don't forget to close your original/old workbook before you run it). This worked for me.

Comment: Ok peh i will do that @peh